# Difference between single commit on branch and trunk

Tags: git, git-diff

I have seen all the questions about diffing files but none that really matches my usecase.

The situation:

```
a - b - c - d (master)
 \ e (tag) - f - g - h (my_branch)
```

Now i would like to see a diff just like if i had cherry-picked `h` onto `d`.

This happens when you are working on a stable version of a software and need to send a patch against trunk.

Anyone know how i can produce such a diff?

Comment: You should `rebase` your branch to master before sending the patch.

Comment: @choroba Yes that is currently what i do. i create a copy of the branch and rebase onto master. That gets tedious after a while and that's why i'm looking for a way to just create the diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>To see the difference between the 2 commits, simply do `git diff h d`.</strike>

**Editing in response to comments**

The fewest steps I can think of is:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick h --no-commit
git diff --staged
git reset --hard
```

Comment: That will also show me the differences that have been introduced in `f`, `g`, `h` and all other commits.

Comment: @RedX Why wouldn't you want that?  After all, you'd care about the differences of those version paths.  Why would you want to compare isolated h vs. isolated d?

Comment: @ThomasStringer the case provided was cherry-picking `h` onto `d` in the case of a patch, in which case you would only want to compare the changes made on that specific commit

Answer (score 0):

The best i can come up with is that you do the cherry pick without committing and then you can see the diff, not very elegant i know

```
git cherry-pick -n <commit>    # get your patch but dont commit
```

and then you can use `git diff` to view the changes and then if you dont actually want to commit them but instead get rid of them

```
git reset    # unstage
git checkout -- application/  # or whatever folder your files are in
```

So thats my best attempt, hope it helps somewhat